# After unlocking the secret mission, do I need to finish Media Blitz to be able to access it?

Tags: starcraft-2

Spoilers below.

I have destroyed the appropriate building in the Media Blitz campaign to unlock the secret mission. I got the notification that it has been unlocked, etc. I really didn't want to bother with finishing Media Blitz again, so I aborted.I looked for the mission once I was back on the ship, but am unable to find the mission. I was hoping that the secret mission unlock would work just like achievements, in that you can do what you need to do for the achievement, and abort the mission and still get it. Do I need to finish Media Blitz to be able to access the secret mission?

summary: Once I have unlocked the secret mission, do I need to finish Media Blitz to be able to access it, or can I abort the mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own experience confirms that yes, you do need to finish 'Media Blitz'.

The secret mission will appear on the star map, same as other "normal" missions.

Edit: note that you will have to play the secret mission before going to Char as once you start that, you won't be able to go back to do it.

Comment: Think of it as the mission after Media Blitz in the Rebellion campaign.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what is happening here is that you cannot unlock the secret mission if you did not unlock it on your first playthrough (which I'm inferring from "don't want to beat *again*").

If you play through Media Blitz, and do not collect the secret documents, you can't unlock the secret mission. If you then later replay the level **after finishing the campaign**, and collect the secret documents, *piercing the shroud* will not unlock.

It is also necessary to actually finish Media Blitz within the campaign as well -- you don't get research points by completing objectives and then aborting (you have to finish the level for the research to accrue) and the secret documents behave in a similar way.

Comment: This can't be true. I completed Media Blitz without finding the documents, then went back and completed it again with the secret documents and got the secret mission. In case changing difficulty matters, the first time I played it on Hard difficulty and the second I played it on Normal.

Comment: Hm. My own anecdotal experience disagrees with that.

When you replayed the mission, had you already completed "All In"? (In my case, I had, and was unable to access the new mission)

Comment: Oh, likely not. I did this immediately after first completing Media Blitz and hadn't advanced the campaign otherwise.

Comment: Okay then, edited my answer to be more true.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot go back and re-do Media Blitz from the Mission Archive to unlock the secret mission.

One thing the other answers have not mentioned, however, is that **you can load one of the automatic saves from when you played through Media Blitz for the first time, then unlock the secret level from there**. After finishing Media Blitz from that save, you can then play the secret level and gain any achievements in which you are interested.

Now, what you do next depends on your goals. If you just wanted the achievements, you can go back to your other campaign and go from there. If you're looking to retain the research or just have a campaign where you've done everything, you'll have to continue your progress from Media Blitz. That kind of sucks if you'd done several missions beyond Media Blitz, but it's better than starting a new campaign.

Comment: re: your flag. I'm not going to clear it myself, but typically there's nothing mods can or would do about dupe answers. I feel my answer's more clear, better worded and more complete. If I wanted to comment, I would've. *shrugs*