# How do you access the "Piercing the Shroud" mission if you've already completed the campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

I beat the campaign and then saw that I was 25/26 on missions. I did some research and found out about the secret level, Piercing the Shroud. I went back and got the secret (avoiding a spoiler here) and then beat the level. However, on my "Mission Archives" screen I can't find that level. Also, I can't get back to the Star Map to select it. What do I have to do to select that level, or do I have to start the campaign over?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SC2 WOL Secret mission: Once it is unlocked, do I have to finish the unlocking mission?] Slightly different question, same answer. (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6015/sc2-wol-secret-mission-once-it-is-unlocked-do-i-have-to-finish-the-unlocking-mi)

Comment: @raven completely different question, and different answer. i'm asking about after you've finished the campaign are you able to access the mission. he's asking if he has to complete the mission in order to access the secret mission.

Comment: did you actually look at the answers to that question? They answer the exact question you ask. Quote: "If you then later replay the level after finishing the campaign, and collect the secret documents, piercing the shroud will not unlock."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to start the campaign over. Or, if you have a saved game before you started the Char mission, you can reload that and you'll have to unlock the secret mission again, but you can play it through the mission archives as long as you're still aboard the Hyperion.

Answer (score 3):

Uh...all these other guys are way off.  Maybe this was fixed somewhere along the way?  At least in whatever the current version of Starcraft II is, *after* you finish the campaign, you can go on back to Media Blitz from the mission screen,  and pick up the secret papers.  Then after you finish the Media Blitz mission again, the Piercing the Shroud mission should appear at the very bottom of the list-after the All In Char mission.  There's not a lot of plot development in this situation, though...it just sends you back to the mission screen after you beat it.

And yes, if you beat Piercing the Shroud like this it does count towards the completionist achievement...